# javascript error is shown in the browser

Tags: javascript

The javascript code is not working. Would you please tell me why its not working? I want two div in equal size whatever the content height is. I took two div inside of a container and put some dummy text inside of two div. stlylesheet is also attached herewith. The browser is throwing this error. "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" .

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
         var leftHeight = $('#left-block').height();
         var rightHeight = $('#right-block').height();
            
         if (leftHeight > rightHeight) {
            rightHeight = leftHeight;
         } else {
            leftHeight = rightHeight;
         }
           
         $('#left-block').css('height','rightHeight');
         $('#right-block').css('height','rightHeight');
     });
```

```css
* {
   -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
           box-sizing:border-box;
  }
       .container:before,
       .container:after {
          content: "";
          display: table;
       }
       .left-block,
       .right-block {
         float: left;
         padding: 20px;
         width: 50%;
       }
       .left-block {
         background: #e4e4e4;
       }
       .right-block {
         background: whitesmoke;
       }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="left-block" class="left-block">
   <p>demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text</p>

   <p>demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text</p>
   <p>demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text</p>
   <p>demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text</p>
   <p>demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text</p>
   <p>demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text</p>
   <p>demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text</p>
  </div>
  <div id="right-block" class="right-block">
   <p>demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text</p>
   <p>demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text</p>
   <p>demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text</p>
   <p>demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text</p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: `$ is not defined`. You need to include jQuery in your code snippet if you're using that.

Comment: Also, assign variable not string. `.css('height',rightHeight);`

Comment: The CSS and HTML is not relevant to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The browser is throwing this error. "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" .

This means that `$` is not defined. `$` in this case refers to jQuery. You're attempting to use functionality from the jQuery library but you're not actually including that in your document at all.

To fix this, simply download jQuery from [the jQuery website](http://jquery.com/download/), and include it in your HTML file using:

```
<script src="path/to/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

(Changing `path/to/jquery` to the folder path relative to your HTML document where you downloaded jQuery to, and changing `jquery.min.js` to the exact file name of the version you downloaded).

---

Furthermore, you're not setting your heights to the values contained in the variables, you're setting them as string values. Change:

```
$('#left-block').css('height','rightHeight');
$('#right-block').css('height','rightHeight');
```

To:

```
$('#left-block').css('height', rightHeight);
$('#right-block').css('height', rightHeight);
```

Do note though that with this, your `leftHeight` variable is never used.

Comment: Thank you very much to all. The code is now working very well. Again, thanks for your kind co-operation.

Comment: @HifzurRahman happy to help. :) If this helped, please mark the answer as Accepted if and when you get the chance. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add reference to jQuery. For example:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

or you can host it with your site by first downloading it from jQuery site.

Comment: Glad to help. Please select one of the answers as "Accepted" (there is check mark under the big 0 ) James had more complete answer than me but it is your choice.